# ¿Cómo refrescar página después de un delete y para conseguir la hora actual?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo dos problemas:

**El primero**, en un *select option* que se carga con la base de datos elijo el registro que voy a borrar una vez borrado me sigue apareciendo en el desplegable del *select*.

¿Cómo hago para que se actualice al instante mi *select option*?

Con este código hago el *delete*:

```
function delete2(id){
  if(confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?")){
  $.ajax({
      url : 'scripts/borrar_conductor.php',
      data : { id : id },
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
        document.getElementById("updateconductor").reset();               
      }
  });
  }  
}
```

**El segundo**, tiene algo de relación. En un *modal*, tengo un *inputext* donde recibo la fecha y hora de mi computadora pero al cerrar y abrir el *modal*, mi hora sigue siendo la misma hasta que actualizo la pagina me cambia a la hora transcurrida.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se refresque el modal y me tome la hora exacta?

Con el siguiente código consigo la hora de mi computadora:

```
<?php 
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');        
      $fecha = date("Y/m/d H:i:s"); //formato solo fecha
      ?>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha_mod" id="fecha_mod" 
      value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
```

De esta manera obtengo los datos de mi BD para llenar el *select* del cual elegiré un dato para eliminarlo:

```
  <select  name="conductor1" id="conductor1" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
            <?php
                $query="SELECT  * FROM conductor";
                $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    
                echo '<option value="'.$row['id_conductor'].'">'.$row['nombre'].'</option>';
              }
            ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: Para el problema uno puedes retornar la lista de nuevos productos y en la linea donde colocas document.getElementById("updateconductor").reset();  debajo puedes mandar a llenar nuevamente la lista. para la fecha puedes hacer lo mismo, podrías retornar un json que traiga la lista nueva y la hora en la que hiciste dicha petición y agregas todo por el js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para borrar el item del select y refrescar el select (por decirlo de alguna manera) lo que puedes hacer seria lo siguiente. Creo una función que sea para mostrar los selects, esta estaría con la que ya tienes de borrar un registro `function delete2(id)` algo asi:

```js
// funcion para eliminar conductores
function delete2(id){
  if(confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?")){
  $.ajax({
      url : 'scripts/borrar_conductor.php',
      data : { id : id },
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(data) {
        console.log("elemento eliminado");          
      }
  });
  }  
}
// funcion para consultar todos los conductores
function consultarConductores(){
  
  $.ajax({
      url : 'scripts/consultar_conductores.php',
      type : 'POST',
      async: false,
      success : function(data) {
        return data;
      }
  });

}

function actualizarSelectsConductores(id){
 //eliminas el registro
 delete2(id);
 //consultas los registros que existen
 var registros = consultarConductores();
 // limpias el select
 $("#conductores").html('');
 // construyes de nuevo el select
  for (var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
    //.. agrega los options al select
  }
}
```

espero te sirva de guía

Comment: Esta solución no tiene sentido, pues está haciendo una petición innecesaria ya que si el resultado del delete es success directamente puedes borrarlo del select sin tener que volver a consultar el listado de nuevo.

Comment: a mi punto de vista no es innecesaria, mas bien es segura. De esta manera estamos seguros que los datos que voy a mostrar en el select son los que están registrados en la base de datos

Comment: No, es innecesaria, pues lo datos ya son robustos desde la primera instancia, la petición sobra. De hecho esto con muchas opciones tendría problemas de rendimiento, por eso no se implementa así en ningún sistema.

Comment: entiendo que una vez borrado un dato se vuelva a hacer la petición de los datos para reconstruir el select option pero la ultima parte seria redundante en volver a consultar no ?

Comment: @Jota déjame ver tu forma de hacerlo para entender tu punto de vista, no volvamos esto una discusión, mas bien ayudemos a el compañero

Comment: @jasieltorres la idea es que la función de consultarConductores() te sirva para futuras consultas a todos los datos de los conductores y no tengas que repetir el mismo proceso siempre.

Comment: Cuando renderizas el select por primera vez ya tienes los datos, no necesitas volver a consultar nada más. Si haces un delete de una opción del select y ha sido success, en el mismo success puedes eliminarlo con total seguridad y ya te quedaría el contenido correcto sin tener que realizar otra petición.

Answer (score 1):

Como el delete lo estás haciendo mediante AJAX y no refrescando la página, tienes que eliminar manualmente el elemento borrado del select mediante javascript en el success de AJAX.
Tu función quedaría:

```
  function delete2(id){
  if(confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?")){
  $.ajax({
      url : 'scripts/borrar_conductor.php',
      data : { id : id },
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(data) {
        // QUITAR AQUI LA OPCION RECIEN BORRADA DEL SELECT MEDIANTE JAVASCRIPT
        // -------------------------
        document.getElementById("updateconductor").reset();               
      }
  });
  }  
}
```

Respecto al modal, no deberías de hacerlo con PHP, si no con javascript:

```
$("#fecha_mod").val(new Date());
$("#id_modal").modal();
```

Cada vez que abras el modal puedes pintar la variable `now` recién calculada.

Pero si el input `fecha_mod` lo estás utilizando para guardar algo en base de datos, tienes que hacerlo en el momento que hagas la inserción en base de datos mediante PHP.

Comment: no entendí bien a que te refieres con : Cada vez que abras el modal puedes pintar la variable now recién calculada.

Comment: Antes de hacer $("#id_modal").modal("show"); para abrir el modal, tendrías que hacer $("#fecha_mod").val(new Date()); para que tengas la fecha actualizada en cuanto abras el modal.

Comment: Excelente, esperemos y sea la solución que busca jasiel :)

Comment: $("#fecha_mod").val(new Date()); esto me funciono cada vez que cierro y abro se me actualiza la hora pero el formato de fecha se cambio a esto :Wed May 15 2019 cuando lo tenia asi 2019/05/115  y al insertar la fecha en la base no meguarda nada

Comment: Si esa fecha de modificación se tiene que almacenar en BD cuando haces el borrado, lo tienes que hacer en PHP cuando hagas la llamada AJAX, no desde el modal.